# SQL - Sum functions with differentcondition

Tags: sql, sum, conditional-statements

So i have this query that consist of 3 columns.
First:

```
Select c1, sum(c2), sum(c3)
from t
where c4 not in ('xxx')
Group by c1
```

Then I get both sum(c2) and sum(c3) based on the condition.

I only want to apply the condition on sum(c3).
How do I do that?

I tried below and it did not work:

```
Select c1, sum(c2), ( select sum(c3) from t where c4 not in ('xxx')) as c3
from t
group by c1
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `CASE` expression with conditional aggregation to compute the `c3` sum:

```
SELECT c1,
       SUM(c2),
       SUM(CASE WHEN c4 NOT IN ('xxx') THEN c3 ELSE 0 END)
FROM t
GROUP BY c1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
Select c1, sum(c2), sum(case c4 when 'xxx' then 0 else c3 end) as c3
from t
group by c1
```